# Regex - Match between Two characters unless contains forward slash

Tags: regex

i know the pattern [^/] will match until the char but how can i match between Two chars unless it contains a /

```
<hello world></hello world>
```

Pattern

```
(?<=<).+?[^/](?=>)
```

so it should match only hello world, and not /hello world

I am using vb.net thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there: you need to repeat the `[^/]` pattern and not the `.` one (which allows `/`):

```
(?<=<)[^/]+?(?=>)
```

To clarify, `[^/]` means "one character, any character except a `/`".